# Why does using a webkit-transition with text result in the text snapping at the end?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, transition

Please see the following: http://jsfiddle.net/2Vdef/1/

When you move your mouse over the div, the text animates in but right at the end has a very unattractive snap into opacity:1. Why so abrupt? How can this be made smooth? Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything abrupt here in Chrome as the text fades in.  What browser are you seeing it in?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.82, it's real jumpy at the end

Comment: I'm using 21.0.1180.83 on Windows Vista - I don't see any jumpiness.

Comment: I see it on Chrome 21 on OS X.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12820319/1491212

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same problem, and while this solution doesn't work in my case it does in yours.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Vdef/13/

Add backface-visibility.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
backface-visibility:         hidden;
```

EDIT: The solution in my case was indeed backface-visbility. You just need to apply it to the correct element. I animated the opacity of `a`, and assumed that `backface-visbility` needed to be applied to `a`. Instead, it needed to be applied to the container of `a`.

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/9PmXu/
Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/9PmXu/1/

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine on Chrome and FF Win 7 / OS X to me, but on IE of course no gradual opacity change. For all browsers, you could try to achieve the same effect with jQuery and tweak the animation speed as you like. http://jsfiddle.net/2Vdef/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
transition: opacity 1s ease;
```

To this:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
```

It should just make all your transition problems be more smooth.

Also, the answer above from @Slave is correct also, but change the '200' to '600' to make it a bit more smooth. The answer is correct,  but my answer is in pure CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the update and the font-weight change but that didnt' have an effect...

Comment: This can have some adverse side effects, e.g. when the page is first loaded all links fade from default blue/purple to custom color. At least in Chrome 21.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can prevent the choppyness with:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

http://chrissilich.com/blog/fix-css-animation-slow-or-choppy-in-mobile-browsers/

Comment: The question isn't asking about choppiness. There is no choppiness. The problem is that the hover transition changes the visual weight of the text, which it shouldn't.

Comment: The answer still helped me. :)