# How to prevent Webkit text rendering change during CSS transition

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm using CSS transitions to transition between CSS transformed states (basically transitioning the scale of an element). I notice that when the element is transitioning, the rest of the text on the page (in Webkit) tends to slightly alter its rendering until the transition is done.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/UeNFK/

I also noticed that this does not occur on my headers, which have the `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` property/value pair on them. So, I'm wondering, is there any way to have the text maintain its default look (the "auto" value for font-smoothing) and not alter rendering during a transition.

I've tried explicitly setting the text to use the "auto" value, but that doesn't do anything. I should also note that setting font-smoothing to "none" also prevents the rendering blink during transition.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I should note that I am on OS X. While looking at my test in Chrome on Parallels, I did not see the two different paragraphs behaving differently, so this may be an issue exclusive to Macs.

Comment: 21. And the Safari version is 6. It happens in both browsers, which makes me think it's Webkit, and not the browser.

Comment: both antialiased and aliased paragraphs are exhibiting same behaviour. chrome Version 23.0.1270.0 canary | 21.0.1180.89 m | 5.17 safari

Comment: I'm guessing you're on the dev release of Chrome. Though, OS may be playing a part in this. I'll edit to the question to note that I am using OSX.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this works, but adding '-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);' to '.antialiased {} seem to fix it. It even works if you add it to 'p {}'. Since I can't explain why this works it didn't feel right to provide it as an answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Christofer That makes them consistent - but it makes them all appear antialiased (they're all thinner text). I'm trying to make the un-antialiased text (the first paragraph) stay in it's default style (which is appearing a bit bolder than the antialiased text).

Comment: Feel free to accept any answer :)

Comment: This actually seems to have been fixed in the updated version of Chrome. Chrome no longer blinks the non-anti-aliased text.

Comment: I find its happening on Windows browsers too so I don't think it's a Mac problem. For me the only working option now is the translateZ(0).

Comment: Hi! Care to accept my answser (or someone else's)? Cheers!

Comment: Does anyone happen to know if this issue has a corresponding bug in Google's tracker?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webkit text aliasing gets weird during CSS3 animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589985/webkit-text-aliasing-gets-weird-during-css3-animations)

Answer (score 84):

I think I found A solution:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

**Forcing hardware acceleration** on the parent element seems to solve the problem...

**EDIT**
As commented, this hack disables font-smoothing and can degrade text rendering depending on your fonts, browser and OS!

Comment: Tried the font-smoothing and it didn't work. Tried this, it worked perfectly

Comment: This did not give me the desired result for this stated issue, but this has help fix other CSS transition problems I've had (like weird blinking text when hiding/showing content within the transitioning element).

Comment: Doesn't work for me whereas -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; and  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; works. Credits go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589985/webkit-text-aliasing-gets-weird-during-css3-animations

Comment: +1 awesome, this is the only method that worked for the situation I found myself in

Comment: This disables font-smoothing in the first place. So you have no font-smoothing at the start of transition, no font-smoothing while transition and no font-smoothing at the end. So no font-smoothing change, but also no font-smoothing at all.

Answer (score 45):

### **UPDATE August 2020**

You no longer need to target Safari with a media query to enable subpixel font smoothing. The default is fine.

**However**, although it uses subpixel font smoothing by default, there's a significant *fly in the ointment* in **Chrome's** font smoothing, for anyone looking for a **consistent rendering of text**.

1. This is Chrome's rendering of light text on a dark background [image: light on dark]
2. This is Chrome's rendering of dark text on a light background [image: dark on light]

Look at the size of the whole in the letter e above. The Light text on a dark background is rendered with a perceptibly heavier weight than the dark text on a light background (with identical css font styling).

One solution, for sites respecting the user's dark / light theme setting, is to target Chrome with a media query that is limited to dark mode and switch it to non subpixel smoothing like so:

```
@media screen
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm)
and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
}
```

The result :

[image: dark on light][image: light on dark antialiased]

A far more consistent text weight regardless of whether rendering light on dark or dark on light.

Check out the side-by-side comparison of before & after:
[image: light on dark][image: light on dark antialiased]

--

**UPDATE May 2018**

`-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` now has no effect in Chrome but in Safari it still improves things a great deal BUT ONLY ON RETINA. Without it in Safari on retina screens text is thin and insipid, whereas with it, text has the proper weight. But if you use this on non retina displays in Safari, (especially at light weight values) text is a disaster. Strongly recommend using a media-query :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  }
}
```

---

Explicitly setting `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` is the best current solution if you wish to at least partially avoid the thinner antialiased text.

--tl;dr--

With both Safari and Chrome where the default font rendering uses subpixel-antialiasing, any CSS that forces GPU based rendering, like the suggestions above to use a transform using translateZ or even just a scale transition, will cause Safari and Chrome to automatically "give up" on subpixel-antialiased font smoothing and instead switch to just antialiased text, which looks a lot lighter and thinner, especially on Safari.

Other responses have focused on maintaining a constant rendering by simply setting or forcing font-smoothing to the thinner antiailiased text. To my eye using translateZ or backface hidden significantly degrades the quality of the text rendering and the best solution if you want the text to just stay consistent and you're OK with the thinner text is just to use `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`. However, explicitly setting `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` does actually have some effect - the text does still change slightly and is just about visibly thinner during transitions rendered on the GPU but not as thin as it goes without this setting. So it looks like this at least partially prevents the switch to straight antiailiased text.

Comment: This is the best solution. All others degrade the the text rendering, which is what OP specifically asked to *avoid*

Comment: Life saver for me! Thanks. Avoids abruptly switching to sub pixel rendering after a css transition. At least with opacity transition this keeps the font on (theoretically always default) sub pixel rendering even during the transition. Great!

Comment: best solution for us! Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I'd come across this over a year ago and forgotten all about it. This is the only solution that resolved the described issue for me.

Answer (score 20):

I've noticed that pretty much every time I'm having graphics issues (flickering/stuttering/choppiness/etc) due to a transition, using -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; on the elements that are acting up tends to solve the problem.

Comment: This is the (currently) correct answer. To my knowledge webkit-font-smoothing was removed a while ago, was supposed to be added again, but currently does not work for me in the latest version of Chrome. The translateZ trick doesn't seem to work anymore either. I guess this can change again at any time. :/

Comment: This caused some text to become blurred for me.

Answer (score 8):

To prevent text rendering changes due to hardware-acceleration, you can either:

1. Set all text to -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased. This means text is thinner and not sub-pixel antialiased.
2. If you want text which is being affected by hardware-acceleration to be sub-pixel antialiased (the default kind of font smoothing), then putting that text inside an input, without borders and disabled, will keep that sub-pixel antialiased (at least on Chrome on Mac OS X). I have not tested this on other platforms, but if sub-pixel antialiasing is important, you can at least use this trick.

Comment: I have tested the option 2 (trick with input element) on Win8.1 and Chrome 47 and it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Firefox on a Mac you'll want to use the following css to fix the issue.

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

More on this at [Webfont Smoothing and Antialiasing in Firefox and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459746/css3-webfont-smoothing-and-antialiasing-in-firefox-and-opera)

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. Hope it helps. Found in other stackoverflow post.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the rendering change you need to set `font-smoothing: antialiased` (or `none`).

The browser disabling subpixel font rendering is likely a side-effect of hardware acceleration. When the background you are rendering against is constantly shifting, the text cannot be rendered on a separate layer, as each frame must be checked against all background layers. This could severely degrade performance.

Apple often disable subpixel font-smoothing on [their](https://www.apple.com) [own](https://www.icloud.com) sites.

Comment: The problem with setting the font-smoothing to antialiased is that the text does not look like I want it to. I want the visual effect of setting font-smoothing to "auto" (the bolder look) - but when you do this, the text will shift during any transition. So, my goal is to just maintain the bold look of "auto" at all times.

Comment: You can work around it by not using hardware acceleration. Use a timer in jQuery and do the the transition by hand (without CSS transition). I am not sure I would recommend it though, as performance and smoothness will be worse.

Comment: True, I could just use jQuery to animate it... That may be the only solution if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above solutions (`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px)` on the element, and `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` on the page) some elements may still behave badly. For me it was placeholder text in an input element: For this, use `position:relative`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Read it carefully:

> I notice that when the element is transitioning, the **rest of the text
>   on the page** (in Webkit) tends to slightly alter its rendering until
>   the transition is done.

none of the solutions above seemed to work. However, setting (things like)

```
#myanimation { -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); }
```

on the element that **has the animation** did work.

By taking the animated element to the GPU layer you take it out of the normal flow of the page rendering (things like z-index will not work anymore too, for example). As a side effect, the animation and the rest of the page wont influence eachother anymore.

If it effects your font rendering, it only does so for the animated element, ofcourse. I don't see the difference in my Chrome.

Comment: I stand corrected. I do see changes in font rendering in the rest of the page, also on places where translateZ(0) is not applied.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me when I had font icons that were getting blurry.  Applied the transform to the sections that were being animated and it solved the problem.

Comment: Dude, this was already answered 2 years ago. Right above...Exact same answer / code.

Comment: yes, my only point was you have to put the `-webkit-transform` on the *element that has the animation*, to prevent rendering changes *on other elements on the page*. but as commented, it worked for a while and stopped working when i changed bits of the page later.