# round image with position fixed - css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get round images in both chrome and mozilla with position fixed but it somehow fails in chrome.

Here is my css :-

```
.circular{

    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 5px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 80px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Here is my html :-

```
 <div class='circular'>
              <div class='round-image'>
                <img alt="Portfolio_page" src="/assets/portfolio_page.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
```

This is the two result in chrome and mozilla :- 
[image: mozilla view]
[image: chrome view]

It was appearing properly till I did not put position: fixed and give a specific height and width

Comment: What version of Chrome? seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Same here, works fine in my version too (v28)

Comment: how to check version?

Comment: On a Vista system goto "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" and right click on Chrome application then Properties a window should open then click on Details - you should now be able to see the version

Comment: Just a thought, if you are using the same version as myself and Sourabh (v28) try clearing your browser cache and see if it helps.

Comment: @Malcom you can also view the Chrome version by clicking on the menu and selecting "About Google Chrome". :-)

Comment: works fine on my browser.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with mine, is there a diff between chrome and chromium?

Comment: I have never used Chromium.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29
but it could be your problem as the article says there are some minor differences I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
.circular img {
    position: static;
}
```

if that doesn't work:

```
.circular{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

i noticed that i could get the same problem if the img was position: fixed. maybe it's somehow inheriting position on the windows version of chrome. the transform can force a repaint which might also fix it

credit for the transform idea: [Chrome rendering issue. Fixed position anchor with UL in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152470/chrome-rendering-issue-fixed-position-anchor-with-ul-in-body)

Comment: Arg.. Worth a try.. Maybe try the transform on the img itself or as a long shot try zindex : -1 on the img