# Bootstrap navbar affix blurry with disappearing workaround in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, affix

At first, I was having a problem with the navbar intermittently disappearing after clicking on a nav link in the navbar. Googling found this to be a bug, and this was suggested as a fix (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32, [Chrome rendering issue. Fixed position anchor with UL in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152470/chrome-rendering-issue-fixed-position-anchor-with-ul-in-body))

```
.affix,.navbar-fixed-top{
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}
```

This worked to prevent the navbar from disappearing. However, I now have a new problem. If the mouse wheel is used to scroll the page, the navbar becomes blurry and moves up and down +/- maybe 1 pixel, as if it is being rendered at a non-integer pixel location depending on the scroll position.

I haven't noticed either problem in IE, just Chrome.

Does anyone have a workaround for the non-integer subpixel location problem?