# Unwanted text movement on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a site for a restaurant and i found a glitch on Chrome.

[demo](http://www.digitalerawebdesign.com/cavo/index.html)

In Chrome when you scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and the sub menu appears, when you hover over the text it seems to move up and down, the only hover action i programmed in was the opacity change. I'm not sure why that happens.

Edit: I found it has something to do with my

```
.nav ul li a:hover {
    opacity: .6;}
```

when this is removed no hover effect is activated and this doesn't happen anymore..

more specifically i think its something to do with

```
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Cant see any movement in chrome!

Comment: I think he means that the top menu changes when you scroll down.

Comment: looks ok to me too, except those images should be jpeg not png some people pay for their bytes.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should fix these: https://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalerawebdesign.com%2Fcavo%2Findex.html

Comment: @flo what version of chrome? I don't see anything in the sub-menu behaving oddly

Comment: works fine in chrome for me too

Comment: @jmore009 im in version Version 39.0.2171.95 m

just to confirm, you guys are scrolling down then then hovering over the navigation not the menu?

Comment: @flo yeah im scrolling down and hovering over "starters", "breakfast and Brunch", etc..thats what you're talking about right?

Comment: it seems to happen to me when im scrolled down about halfway through the starters menu...

Comment: hey guys, I think i found source of the problem, I think it has something to do with opacity.. please look at first post

Comment: Please stop prefixing `transition` - it's been unprefixed in every common browser for over a year now. It's never even been prefixed in IE so `-ms-transition` was never required.

Comment: Solved my own problem, but thanks for the down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a problem with webkit where opacity transition makes everything move in my head by 1px

the solve was

```
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0);
```

[image moves on hover - chrome opacity issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980153/image-moves-on-hover-chrome-opacity-issue)