# Chrome CSS transition opacity on hover jumpy issue

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying the most simple of opacity transitions in Chrome, but I'm finding that although often it is smooth, sometimes it jumps straight to opacity: 0 or opacity: 1, without transitioning.

Simplified version, just for webkit:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        background-color: #ff0000;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
   }
   .box:hover{
       opacity:0;
   }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhydbakn/

I find the best way to make it go wrong is to roll over, click, roll off, roll over again, wait for it to reach opacity: 0, then really slowly (pixel by pixel) roll off the image in a downwards direction. When I do this, half the time it will jump straight back to opacity:1 instead of transitioning smoothly.

I'm Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m on Windows 7. Have tested on a colleague's PC and found the same issue.

Here's a video of it going wrong. It works until about half way: http://webm.host/41dce/

Comment: running chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 m also on Windows 7, it isn't happening for me

Comment: Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m on Windows 7 - Cannot recreate the issue using your provided steps in the given fiddle.

Comment: Cannot recreate the issue. Anyways, perhaps, you can use 
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

Comment: Versión 45.0.2454.101 m here on windows 8.1 working fine

Comment: I just went back to my fiddle and also couldn't reproduce it, until I clicked the red box, then after rolling off and on again it happened. Perhaps the fiddle needs focus to go wrong?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16833496/1245276

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated code:

```
<style>
.box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

    will-change: opacity;
}
.box:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Note the default opacity added to your `.box` container, an easing function and default hardware acceleration by using a transform declaration.

Note that I cannot reproduce your issue. It might be a browser thing.

**UPDATE 2022**: I have added CSS prefixes. Omit all `-webkit-` and `-o-` if you are building for modern browsers only.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, I've tried all the things above - hardware acceleration, setting a default opacity, using different easing, different times (does seem to happen less the longer the transition takes), have tried transitioning 'all' instead of just 'opacity', have added a delay (it waits for the delay and then jumps instantly) have tried transitioning on a div inside .box with the :hover on .box. Always the same!

Comment: Do you have other transitions on the parent element? Or using the `*` selector?

Comment: No, just what you can see in the example code. I've just uploaded a video showing it in action: http://webm.host/41dce/

Comment: What happens if you create an empty page with only that effect? No other code.

Comment: Yes, before I put it on fiddle it was a single HTML page with nothing but the .box div and the css. Even with just this, it still has this problem - on three of the computers in our office.

Comment: Tested the fiddle again about 20 times, it works fine for me. It's really weird.

Comment: Agreed, it's really wierd. Thanks for all your effort trying to replicate it!

Comment: Still applies in 2022... mad!

Answer (score -3):

This should fix your issue

```
$(".box").mouseenter(
  function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:'0'},'1000')
  });
$(".box").mouseleave(
  function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity:'1'},'1000')
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhydbakn/2/

Comment: The OP did not ask for a jQuery solution. He might not even use jQuery inside his project.

Comment: Not the solution I want, but it did make me think - I got the same problem when triggering the transition with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/bhydbakn/3/