# Element moved when I hover mouse

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Why when I hover mouse on cards image moved ?!
I am trying to fix it and I find when I remove page `direction` and or remove `overflow-y` from `#center` it's fixed but I need them !!

even when I inspect elements in cards and mouse hovering could to see all elements are moved but shown correct ! 
 I guess it's maybe page rendering problem in chrome browser
in fact what is problem and how can I to fix it technically ?

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a3stn5ct/)

Comment: Try using flexbox instead of floating. This can be achieved very easily with flexbox.

Comment: why negative point !? it's a problem and question with real demo !

Comment: Actually I gave a upvote for such a good question along with demo. Don't know who gave downvote.

Comment: try backface-visibility: hidden on .div. It does solve your problem. This is a known issue. See @Thai Hoc Ha Nguyen answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be a Chrome bug according to this topic:
[image moves on hover - chrome opacity issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980153/image-moves-on-hover-chrome-opacity-issue/12995086#12995086)
and I think you should setting position:relative to inner img solves the problem

Comment: Thanks for hint and your solution , it's fixed by set posision:relative; to card div ".div"  https://jsfiddle.net/a3stn5ct/2/

Comment: @javaacm you're welcome. I don't know why some people auto downvote the question, I gave you an upvote with real code demo. Be always positive my friend