# Making floating image transparent on hover causes it to 'jump'

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to make an image that's wrapped in an `a` tag darken on hover. To do this I simply made the wrapping `a` tag's background black and applied:

```
a:hover > img {
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

to the image.

This works, but I get a weird 'jumpy' issue when image element containers have `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` applied. This only occurs on some images.

You can see this happening here when you hover over the middle image: https://jsfiddle.net/4566a85t/

Would anyone know how I could prevent this?

My code is:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTojc9ycyhwL6TnP_lEhQrTXy8Cjrs738WeDmnDOmIXGmR20NEJTw">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTojc9ycyhwL6TnP_lEhQrTXy8Cjrs738WeDmnDOmIXGmR20NEJTw">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTojc9ycyhwL6TnP_lEhQrTXy8Cjrs738WeDmnDOmIXGmR20NEJTw">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

a {
  background: black;
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

a:hover > img {
  opacity: .8;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

EDIT:

I tried using `-webkit-filter: brightness(70%);` with no black background, but had the same issue. Seems to be the transition that's the problem.

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is incorrect.

Comment: @fubar oops sorry. Fixed.

Comment: @MeltingDog I checked your jsfiddle, but I don't see any weird 'jumpy' issue you mentioned, tested on chrome and firefox and cute puppy!

Comment: I didn't either, until I made the window wider, then it jumps on hover.

Comment: @Vincent1989 try making the viewing area as large as possible. Its more pronounced when it's larger.

Comment: See if my reply works

Comment: @Vincent1989 sorry, no luck - same issue. Seems to be happening in your example too.

Comment: This should solve it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980153/image-moves-on-hover-chrome-opacity-issue

Comment: @MeltingDog Try my updated post

Comment: @MeltingDog Sorry I don't think it works as well

Comment: @fubar sorry, still get the same little jump

Comment: @MeltingDog - interesting. It fixed the problem for me in your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/4566a85t/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reset the browser default css first and add in `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to image as suggested in the comments

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

img{
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Source:**

[image moves on hover - chrome opacity issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980153/image-moves-on-hover-chrome-opacity-issue)

**Example:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  background: black;
  display: block;
}

img {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

a>img {
  opacity: 1;
}

a:hover>img {
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e5/0d/17/e50d177765012ab2e70f8bccb5dc884a--pug-puppies-pug-dogs.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e5/0d/17/e50d177765012ab2e70f8bccb5dc884a--pug-puppies-pug-dogs.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e5/0d/17/e50d177765012ab2e70f8bccb5dc884a--pug-puppies-pug-dogs.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: below will only work for Webkit browsers

OK got it!

I used `-webkit-filter: brightness();` and set the initial img to `-webkit-filter: brightness(100%);`

My new code:

```
a > img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}

a:hover > img {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Update fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4566a85t/2/

Comment: You realise that'll only work in webkit browsers, right?

Comment: @fubar you're right. I reworked my code with your solution again and it seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that when it starts to animate CSS doesn't know the right size that's why it's like adjusting during the first frames.

But if you will set a fixed width of the wrapper. e.g.

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Yep you are correct - applying the fixed width works. Thing is I don't want a fixed width.