# CSS animation using filter blur causing "text jump" on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I've created this FadeInLeftBLur animation which is causing a "flickering" at the end of the animation only in Chrome.

```html
<div id="text" class="fadeLeftBlurAnimate fadeLeftBlurAnimated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum, lorem in lacinia congue, augue eros ultricies nisl, sit amet ornare felis nunc vel arcu</div>
```

```css
#text{
  font-size: 30px;
}
.fadeLeftBlurAnimate {
    opacity: 0;
    will-change: filter, transform, opacity;
}
.fadeLeftBlurAnimated {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeLeftBlurAnimation;
    animation-duration: 1600ms;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
@keyframes fadeLeftBlurAnimation {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-10%);
        filter: blur(16px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        filter: blur(0);
    }
}
```

and here an example: https://jsbin.com/jaralid/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image moves on hover when changing filter in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914821/image-moves-on-hover-when-changing-filter-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the `cubic-bezier` function. The last number is causing that "jump." You should probably report a bug. If you set that last number to something less than 0.9, it should look fine. Until it's fixed, use 0.89:

```
/*                                                         This number*/
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 0.89);
```

Comment: It looks like it won't get fixed. There is [an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796963&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=filter%20blur&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=) which is already two years old

Comment: @Bouvanni [the duplicate](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795528) says it is fixed.