# CSS Translate causes typo to break

Tags: css, fonts, translate-animation

I'm trying to add an effect to a menu I use on a website. 
The effect is the first one of the list with a color change added: http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/

But when I try to apply it to my case I have a weird problem that happens on the not hovered element. You can see that the elements that are not hovered change opacity and font-size during the hover on an element.

I added the demo here :

```css
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* Effect 15: scale down, reveal */
 .cl-effect-15 a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.cl-effect-15 a::before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    content:'[';
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    transform: translateX(20px);
}
.cl-effect-15 a::after, .cl-effect-15 a::before {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.cl-effect-15 a::after {
    margin-left: 10px;
    content:']';
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}
.cl-effect-15 a:hover::before, .cl-effect-15 a:hover::after, .cl-effect-15 a:focus::before, .cl-effect-15 a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(1px);
    font-size: 14px;
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #282F47;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background-image: url(../img/BlueJean.svg);
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 .block_content {
    text-align:center;
    color:#ababab;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:"trajanpro_regular";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 ul li:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 ul li a {
    color: #9099AF;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family:"Cinzel";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s ease;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
.totblockhtml.html_2 ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block totblockhtml html_2">
    <div class="block_content">
        <ul class="top_menu ">
            <li class="top_menu_search cl-effect-15"><a href="#">Rechercher</a>

            </li>
            <li class="top_menu_sell cl-effect-15"><a href="#">Vendre</a>

            </li>
            <li class="top_menu_advice  cl-effect-15"><a href="#">Conseils </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it runs fine in chrome 37 for me - on what browser are you having issues?

Comment: everything is running fine on FireFox 24.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Webkit text rendering change during CSS transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502234/how-to-prevent-webkit-text-rendering-change-during-css-transition)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code changing the opacity:

```
.cl-effect-15 a::after, .cl-effect-15 a::before {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}
```

and here's the one changing the font-size:

```
.cl-effect-15 a:hover::before, .cl-effect-15 a:hover::after, .cl-effect-15 a:focus::before, .cl-effect-15 a:focus::after {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I set font-size to 12px and opacity to 1, check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73za0b5k/)