# CSS button hover makes text blinking

Tags: css, html, sass, hover, transform

I have button transformation on hover in my custom stylesheet. It allows me to create button from `<a href>` or `<div>`. During this transformation font is blinking in strange way. Could you kindly tell me why and how to solve it?

Here is the scss code:
https://gist.github.com/rafpiek/7e1b2df5690baa3b02e88eee10adfb98

and the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c4D96FukuQ&feature=youtu.be

```css
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ECECEC;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #B3595F;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.30s linear;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.button:-webkit-any-link {
  color: #ECECEC;
}
.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.07);
  color: #ECECEC;
}
.button:active, .button:focus, .button:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ECECEC;
}
.button.blue {
  background-color: #2C92FF;
}
.button.red {
  background-color: #FF2113;
}
.button.green {
  background-color: #1EBE32;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">button</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Webkit text rendering change during CSS transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502234/how-to-prevent-webkit-text-rendering-change-during-css-transition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in .button:

`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: Could you please mark it as right? It'd help me a lot collecting my 50 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused AFAIK from the browser changing the text antialias type during the animation (new GPU implicit layer).

More info on causes and `fixes` here -> [How to prevent Webkit text rendering change during CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502234/how-to-prevent-webkit-text-rendering-change-during-css-transition)

Answer (score 0):

Can be reduced using perspective and 3d scale:

`transform: perspective(1px) scale3d(1.07,1.07,1);`